# Bugs when fitting Multi label text classification models

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, nlp, classification, logistic-regression

I am now trying to fit a classification model for a Multi label text classification problem.

I have a train set `X_train` that contains list of cleaned text, like

```
["I am constructing Markov chains with  to  states and inferring     
transition probabilities empirically by simply counting how many 
times I saw each transition in my raw data",
"I know the chips only of the  players of my table and mine obviously I 
also know the total number of chips the max and min amount chips the 
players have and the average stackIs it possible to make an 
approximation of my probability of winningI have,
...]
```

and a train multiple tags set `y` corresponding to each text in `X_train`, like

```
[['hypothesis-testing', 'statistical-significance', 'markov-process'],
['probability', 'normal-distribution', 'games'],
...]
```

Now I want to fit a model that could predict the tags in a text set `X_test` that has same format as `X_train`.

I have used the `MultiLabelBinarizer`  to convert the tags and used `TfidfVectorizer` to convert the cleaned text in train set.

```
multilabel_binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
multilabel_binarizer.fit(y)
Y = multilabel_binarizer.transform(y)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = stopWordList)
vectorizer.fit(X_train)
x_train = vectorizer.transform(X_train)
```

But when I try to fit the model I always get bugs.I have tried `OneVsRestClassifier` and `LogisticRegression`.

When I fit a `OneVsRestClassifier` model I got bugs like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/envs/data3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 317, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/data3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 348, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/data3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/data3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 268, in handle
    poll(accum_updates)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 241, in poll
    if func():
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 245, in accum_updates
    num_updates = read_int(self.rfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 714, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

When I fit a `LogisticRegression` model I got bugs like

```
/opt/conda/envs/data3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/sag.py:326: ConvergenceWarning: The max_iter was reached which means the coef_ did not converge
  "the coef_ did not converge", ConvergenceWarning)
```

Anyone knows where the problem is and how to solve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OneVsRestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html) fits one classifier per class. You need to tell it which type of classifier you want (for example Losgistic regression).

The following code works for me:

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression())
classifier.fit(x_train, Y)

X_test= ["I play with Markov chains"]
x_test = vectorizer.transform(X_test)

classifier.predict(x_test)
```

output: array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]])